# User access to the taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms

After upgrading or installing the module (trying to set up a forum for moderation), I lost the visibility of taxonomy for non-admin. Under Admin I can see the content of the entire website as a guest or authorized user materials on taxonomy unavailable.

> There is currently no content classified with this term.

Yes, there is a message updating the rights

> The content access permissions need to be rebuilt. Rebuild permissions.

Rebuilding the permissions fails with an error.

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500
>   Debugging information follows.
>   Path: /batch?render=overlay&id=5478&op=do
>   StatusText: Service unavailable (with message)
>   ResponseText: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'alenkiykin_drup.dr_file_metadata' doesn't exist: SELECT * FROM {file_metadata} WHERE fid IN (:fids_0); Array ( [:fids_0] => 38 ) in file_entity_file_load() (line 183 of...`

Perhaps the problem is in the database.